# How to create jquery editable tables using Bootstrap's typeahead functionality

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, autofill, typeahead

I have two functions that individually work well.  The first one uses Bootstrap's typeahead functionality.  The second one allows an HTML table cell to be editable without doing a submit or page refresh.  What I want done is combine the two WITHOUT writing a whole new function for it.  For example: When a user double-clicks the table cell, I want the textbox to be typeahead enabled so that as he begins to type an entry, valid entries begin to show up in the menu below. Once the user makes his selection, the underlying database table is updated as normal when the focus is lost.

I thought I could just add an event to "editable" like this:

```
cell.on('keydown', function() {$(".autofill").typeahead();});
```

But no luck with that :-(.  Any suggestions?  Below is the code of both functions....
BTW, I'm using Bootstrap version 2.1.1 and Jquery 1.8.3

```
$(document).ready(function(){

/************************************************************
              USING BOOTSTRAP'S TYPEAHEAD 
************************************************************/
$('.autofill').typeahead({
  source: function (query, process) {
    query = $(".autofill").val();
    link = 'ajax/gdata.aspx';
    sp = $(".autofill").attr("proc");
    src = $(".autofill").attr("src");
    if(!src) src = "No Source";

        $.get(link, {desc:query}, function(data) {
          var x = $.parseJSON(data);
          codes = [];
          map = {}; 
          $.each(x, function(i, cd) {
            map[cd.code_desc] = cd;
            codes.push(cd.code_desc);
            process(codes);
          });
        });
  },

  matcher: function(item) {
    if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) { 
      return true;
    }
  },

  sorter: function(items) {
    return items.sort();
  },

  highlighter: function(item) {
    var regex = new RegExp( '(' + this.query + ')', 'gi' );
    return item.replace( regex, "<b>$1</b>" );
  },

  updater: function(item) {
    d = $(".autofill").attr("show");
    selectedItem = map[item].code;
    if (d == 0) {
      return selectedItem;  //return code
    } else {
      return item;      //return description
    }
  }
});


/************************************************************
  Edit underlying table's column directly from HTML table.
        An editable field is highlighted in yellow
************************************************************/
$(".editable").dblclick(function() {
  var a = $.url().param("type");
  var b = $.url().param("id");
  var c = $.url().param("grpid");
  var d = $("input[name='step']").val();
  var e = $(this).attr("data-cap");
  var f = $(this).attr("data-ihtml");
  var m = "table";
  var warn = "#warn" + d;
  var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
  var type = $(this).attr("data-rec");
  var db = "MyDB";
  var tab = a + b + '_' + type;
  var column = $(this).attr("data-col");
  var idcol = $(this).attr("data-idcol");
  var idcolval = $(this).attr("data-idcolval");
  var cell = $(this);
  var cellWidth = cell.attr("width");
  var prevContent = cell.text();
  var URL = "ajax/p.aspx";
  var et = $(this).attr("entry-type");
  var s = $(this).attr("show");
  var src = $(this).attr("src");

  if(!src) {
    src = '""';
  }

  if(!s) {
    s = "1";
  }

  if(!e) {
    e = "Y";
  }

  if(!et) {
    et = "";
  }

  if(!f) {
    if(et == "") var f = '<input type="text" name="newValue" size="4" value="' + prevContent + '" id="txt' + id + '" />';
    if(et == "autofill") var f = '<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" class="autofill" autocomplete="off" proc="1" show="' + s + '" name="newValue" size="4" value="' + prevContent + '" id="txt' + id + '" />';
  }

  var form = '<form action = "javascript: this.preventDefault">' + f + '</form>';
  var msg = "Changes will take effect immediately after moving off this cell!";

  $(warn).html('');
  $(warn).append('<div class="alert alert-warning">' + msg  + '</div>');
  cell.html(form).find('input[type=text]').focus().select().attr('width', cellWidth);
  cell.on('click', function() {return false;});
  cell.focusout(function() {
    var newContent = $("#txt" + id).val();
    var newVal = newContent;
    var g = f.slice(f.search("select"), 7);
    if (g == "select") {
      var h = "#txt" + id + " option:selected";
      newContent = $(h).text();
    }
    if (newContent == "") {
      cell.text(prevContent);
      return false;
    }
    if (newContent == prevContent) {
      cell.text(prevContent);
      return false;
    }

    if (e == "Y") {
      newVal = newVal.toUpperCase();
      newContent = newContent.toUpperCase();
    }

    var formData = 'type=' + a + '&id=' + b + '&grpid=' + c + '&modal=' + m + '&db=' + db + '&tab=' + tab + '&col=' + column + '&val=' + newVal + '&idcol=' + idcol + '&idcolval=' + idcolval + '&orig=' + prevContent + '&cap=' + e;

    $.ajax({
      url   : URL,
      type  : "POST",
      data  : formData,
      dataType  : "html"
    })
      .done(function(msg) {
    //console.log(msg);

    if(!msg) {
      $(warn).html('');
      $(warn).append('<div class="alert alert-success">' + "Record successfully updated!" + '</div>');
          //location.reload(true);
      cell.text(newContent);
    } else {
      $(warn).html('');
      $(warn).append('<div class="alert alert-error">' + msg + '</div>');
      cell.text(prevContent);
    }
    }); 
  });   
});

});
```

Comment: Do you mean Bootstrap v2's typeahead widget, or Twitter's Typeahead.js widget?

Comment: Bootstrap v2's widget, not Twitter's Typeahead.js which is used with Bootstrap v3....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question is no fun, but I figured I could help someone save hours of frustration on a topic that is seldom covered.  So I came up with a workaround that works like a champ that has been in production for two weeks now with no issues! First reverse the order of execution: Enable typeahead first and then auto-update the field on change. Second, add a hidden field in DOM to store the key value of the typeahead-enabled textbox. Finally, change both procedures into functions to: getData(e) and updateNow(e) that can be called at run-time. The auto-update function, UpdateNow(e) will look for changes to the hidden field (NOT the typeahead-enabled textbox) before updating the database with its value.  Additional data attributes were added to enhance functionality and generic re-useability such as the requirement that the list of state values be dependent on the country code selected.  Here is the modified code:

```
/************************************************************
              USING BOOTSTRAP'S TYPEAHEAD 
************************************************************/
getData("#auto_idst");
getData("#auto_idctry");


function getData(elem) {
$(elem).typeahead({
  source: function (query, process) {
    var query = $(elem).val();
    var link = 'ajax/gdata.aspx';
    data_fld = $(elem).attr("data-fld");
    var src = $(elem).attr("src");
    var dependence = $(elem).attr("data-slave");
    if(!dependence) {dependence = "";}
    var ctry = $("#" + dependence).val();
    if(!ctry) {ctry = "";}
    if(!src) var src = 0;
    if(src == '3') {link = 'ajax/gdata.aspx?c=' + ctry;}

    $.get(link, {desc:query, src:src}, function(data) {
      var x = $.parseJSON(data);
      codes = [];
      map = {}; 
      $.each(x, function(i, cd) {
        map[cd.code_desc] = cd;
        codes.push(cd.code_desc);
        process(codes);
      });
    });
  },

  matcher: function(item) {
    if (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(this.query.trim().toLowerCase()) != -1) { 
      return true;
    }
  },

  sorter: function(items) {
    return items.sort();
  },

  highlighter: function(item) {
    var regex = new RegExp( '(' + this.query + ')', 'gi' );
    return item.replace( regex, "<b>$1</b>" );
  },

  updater: function(item) {
    d = $(elem).attr("show");
    selectedItem = map[item].code;

    if (d == 0) {
      $("#" + data_fld).val(selectedItem);
      $("#" + data_fld).trigger("change");
      return selectedItem;  //return code
    } else {
      $("#" + data_fld).val(item);
      $("#" + data_fld).trigger("change");
      return item;      //return description
    }
  }
});
};


/************************************************************
  Edit underlying table's column directly from HTML table.
************************************************************/

$(".now").on("change", function() {
 if ($(this).is(":checkbox")) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    id = "#" + id;
  } else {
    var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
    id = "#" + id;
  }

  updateNow($(id));
});



$(this).on("focusout", function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  val = $.trim(val);

  if (val == "") {
    var c = $(".now").val();
    $(this).val(c);
  }
});


function updateNow(e) {
  var t = e.attr("data-rec");
  var p = e.attr("data-fld");
  var warn = "#stat_" + p;
  var type = $.url().param("type");
  var id = $.url().param("id");
  var grpid = $.url().param("grpid");
  var db = e.attr("data-db");
  var tab = type + id + '_' + t;
  var col = e.attr("data-col");
  var idcol = e.attr("data-idcol");
  var idcolval = e.attr("data-idcolval");
  var oldval = e.attr("data-oldval");
  var URL = "ajax/p.aspx";
  var m = "table";

/*======================================================
  First find out if element is a checkbox.  If so, find
  out if it's checked.  If so, set newval to it's value;
  otherwise, set it to blank.
========================================================*/
   if (e.is(":checkbox")) {
    var chk = e.is(":checked");
    if (chk == "1") {
      var newval = e.val();
    } else {
      var newval = "";
      var control = "#" + e.attr("data-master");
      if (!control) {
        control = "";
      } else {
        $(control).attr("data-oldval", newval);
      }
    }
  } else if (e.is("select")) {
    var newval = "";
    var mm = $("#" + p + "_mm").val();
    var dd = $("#" + p + "_dd").val();
    var yy = $("#" + p + "_yy").val();
    var omm = $("#" + p + "_mm").attr("data-oldval");
    var odd = $("#" + p + "_dd").attr("data-oldval");
    var oyy = $("#" + p + "_yy").attr("data-oldval");

    if ((!mm) || (!dd) || (!yy)) {
      var newval = $("#" + p).val();
    }
    else {
      var sel_dt = 1;
      newval = mm + dd + yy;
      oldval = omm + odd + oyy;
    }
  } else {
      var newval = $("#" + p).val();
  }


  newval = newval.toUpperCase();
  var formData = 'type=' + type + '&id=' + id + '&grpid=' + grpid + '&modal=' + m + '&db=' + db + '&tab=' + tab + '&col=' + col + '&idcol=' + idcol + '&idcolval=' + idcolval + '&val=' + newval + '&orig=' + oldval;
  if((!db) || (!idcol) || (!idcolval)) return false;     

  $.ajax({
    url     : URL,
    type    : "POST",
    data    : formData,
    dataType    : "html"
  })
    .done(function(msg) {
    //console.log(msg);
    if(!msg) {
      $(warn).html('');
      var i = '<img src="assets/images/icon-good.png" />';
      $(warn).html(i);
      e.attr("data-oldval", newval);
      if (sel_dt == 1) {
        $("#" + p + "_mm").val(mm);
        $("#" + p + "_dd").val(dd);
        $("#" + p + "_yy").val(yy);
      } else { 
        e.val(newval); 
      }
    }
    else {
      $(warn).html('');
      var i = '<a href="#" title="' + msg + '"><img src="assets/images/icon-bad.png" /></a>';
      if (sel_dt == 1) {
        $("#" + p + "_mm").val(omm);
        $("#" + p + "_dd").val(odd);
        $("#" + p + "_yy").val(oyy);
      } else { 
        e.val(oldval);
      }
      $(warn).html(i);
    }
    }); 
};
```

Your DOM table should have something similar to this:

```
<td><span id="stat_idctry"></span> ID Issuing Country:</td><td><input name="f4A_idctry" type="text" id="auto_idctry" class="autofill input-large" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" maxlength="50" data-db="1" data-col="id_iss_ctry" data-idcol="seq" data-idcolval="1" data-rec="4A" data-fld="idctry" data-oldval="" show="0" src="1" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="h_idctry" id="idctry" data-id="auto_idctry" class="now" value="" /></td>
<td><span id="stat_idst"></span> ID Issuing State:</td><td><input name="f4A_idst" type="text" id="auto_idst" class="autofill input-mini" data-provide="typeahead" autocomplete="off" maxlength="15" data-db="1" data-col="id_iss_st" data-oldval="" data-idcol="seq" data-idcolval="1" data-rec="4A" data-fld="idst" show="0" src="3" data-slave="idctry" value="" /><input type="hidden" name="h_idst" id="idst" data-id="auto_idst" class="now" value="" /></td>
```

A few notes on the data attributes used here.  For typeahead to work using the getData(e) function above, you must use class="autofill", data-provide="typeahead", and src must have a value.  In my implementation, the src attribute is used as a parameter to a stored procedure in the back-end that pulls the desired data into the textbox.  Doing so, allows me to use one stored procedure for multiple kinds of typeahead textboxes and use the same ajax URL link.  Setting autocomplete="off" prevents modern browsers from auto completing the textbox with previously used values for the user while he or she is typing values. Setting show="0" forces the textbox to display the key value instead of the displayed description.  A value other than "0" for show will display the selected description in the textbox, giving me a degree of flexibility for cases when I need the code as opposed to the description.  The data-slave attribute is used by typeahead to set an additional parameter to obtain the correct data in the dependent textbox based on the value in the textbox indicated by the data-slave attribute.

For auto-update, you must set the hidden field's class to "now" and the data-id to the same ID of the typeahead textbox that updates its value.  This allows the auto-update function to look at other critical data attributes in the typeahead textbox such as: data-db, data-col, data-idcol, data-idcolval, and data-rec. Yes, it's true that I could have added the additional data attributes to the hidden field instead, but that would require me having to cut and paste the necessary data attributes into the hidden field from the original textbox.  You could do it either way, but if you do, make sure you change this piece of code to:

```
$(".now").on("change", function() {
 if ($(this).is(":checkbox")) {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    id = "#" + id;
  } else {
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    id = "#" + id;
  }

  updateNow($(id));
});
```